# R: error when printing character() in assert_that message

Tags: r, printf, character, assertthat

I would like to assert some expressions involving certain variable that is potentially evaluated to `character()`. I would like to print an assertation message showing the value of the variable which can be `character()`.

```
assertthat::assert_that(<expr containing variable [x]>, msg = sprintf("Test for x failed on value %s" , x))

## Variable [x] is a character variable that can be character() or other conventional characters like `"a"`, `"b"` or ``"c"``.
```

Below is a simplified example to show the error I obtained when the variable is evaluated to `character()`:

```
assertthat::assert_that(FALSE, msg = sprintf("%s", character()))
```

gives me error

```
## > Error in stop(assertError(attr(res, "msg"))) : bad error message
```

However the `sprintf` itself works well

```
sprintf("%s", character())
## character(0)

sprintf("%s", character()) %>% typeof
## [1] "character"
```

**What I have tried:**

- Wrap `%s` with backticks `` assert_that(FALSE, msg = sprintf("`%s`", character())) ``
- Load the `assertthat` package first with `library(assertthat)` then call `assert_that(...)`
- Assign first `character()` to a variable and call that variable in `assert_that` which is actually more similar to my real life use case

  ```
  v <- character()
  assert_that(FALSE, msg = sprintf("`%s`", v))
  ```
- Assign the return value of `sprintf` call to a variable and then feed it into the call of `assert_that`

  ```
  v <- character()
  errmsg <- sprintf("`%s`", v)
  assert_that(FALSE, msg = errmsg)
  ```

All gave same error. It seems something inside `assert_that` affects.

What would be the reason of the error and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem arises because you are not loading the assertthat package?

Comment: @IRTFM I have tried also load it first with `library(assertthat)` then call `assert_that(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your `sprintf` statements results in a character with length `0`:

```r
length(sprintf("%s", character()))
#> [1] 0
```

This means there is not really a message for `assert_that` to print. So you have to ensure the length of the `sprintf` output has a length of 1:

```r
require(assertthat)
#> Loading required package: assertthat
assert_that(F, msg=character())
#> Error in stop(assertError(attr(res, "msg"))) : bad error message
assert_that(F, msg=letters[1:2])
#> Error in stop(assertError(attr(res, "msg"))) : bad error message
assert_that(F, msg=letters[1])
#> Error: a
```